# Project in eclipse not resolving jars present in Maven dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I become pretty much confused while working with eclipse and maven. I am trying to create a project which has the package structure as below:

[image]

Now in `DbSIngleton.java` file I am referencing `EmbeddedDriver` class `org.apache.derby.jdbc` package. But it is unable to resolve that, which is strange as the jar is present in the maven dependencies as shown in the image. Also there is another jar `twitter4j` which is getting referenced without any error. Why is it failing for this derby jar? AM I missing something?

The code:

```java
private DbSingleton() {
    
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    if(conn != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Use getConnection() method to create");
    }
    
    if(instance != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to create");
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
 
   <name>demo</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 
   <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
 
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0,)</version>
      </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
     <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
     <version>10.11.1.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 
 
   </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the test scope

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
     <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
     <version>10.11.1.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

should be

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
     <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
     <version>10.11.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Twitter dependency is in the default scope. Hence it is getting resolved.